# How to get div content in form input?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am developing an ecommerce site using `simplecartjs.org`, everything on that script works by div. I need to get `product id`, inside a div tag, in an input field.

for example,

```
<div class="product_id1">0033456</div>
```

in order to make payment page work i need to provide this`product id` on cart page and then post that id to payment page.

is there any way i can get product id in input? e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="product_id1" value="0033456"/>
```

Comment: Tagging your question with JavaScript might help you here

Answer (score 0):

Put `id` attribute in division `<div></div>`:-

```
<div class="product_id1" id="productid">0033456</div>
```

Now, Use javascript :-

```
//Get data from division (inner data from div)    
    var innerdata=document.getElementById('productid').innerHTML; 

//Set text field data here    
    document.getElementById('product_id1').value=innerdata;
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: hi JDeveloper and Kishan Patel, please note that there can one or more <div> product_id. e.g. if user adds one product then there will be only one div and input. there will be three input in form if user adds three products. also, please elaborate more because i am html developer

Comment: Is the products are added dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var product_id1 = $('div.product_id1').html();
 $('#product_id1').val(product_id1);
});
```